# how to open multiple files at once with an executable

Tags: java, image, exe

The situation:

- Java 6 , Windows XP , Eclipse
- I've got an .exe made out ouf an executable .jar.
- It is an application which uses a GUI.

The program is supposed to read - or later on write - metadata in images (jpeg ... ). 
If the program's open you can load one or more files at once using a filechooser.

So far i'm able to select one (image-) file in my file-system ( windows ), click [Open With ... ] and choose my program - the .exe for opening the selected - single - file.

What I'd like to achieve : Selecting more than one file - for example the whole folder by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and open all the images at once.

In my main method the String[] args does only contain one element no matter how much there have been selected.

The code of the main class:

```
public class Starter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Exif e = new Exif("Exif ... ");

        //try{ Thread.sleep(1000); }catch(Exception ex){}

        e.init();

        e.setSize(1024,700);
        e.setSize(1024,600);

        // The array is handled by a gui-class which reads the Strings from the array
        // and opens the referenced files one by one ...
        // Like : 
        //         for(String filename : args
        //         { open(filename); }

        e.open(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try selecting the files that you want and dragging them on top of that exe?

Comment: And in this year the Genius-Award goes to ... ... Vic! It did not even come to my mind to do that. Thanks!